# ipython: change syntax highlighting color for matching parenthesis

Tags: terminal, ipython, color-scheme

I am using ipython 5.8.0 on Debian 10

Following screenshot shows the colors of normal command, and a command when my cursor moves to a parenthesis and matching parenthesis are highlighted:

[image]

This color scheme is unfortunate. Where can I change this?

## UPDATE:

This solution no longer works for `ipython3` version `8.5.0`. When I add it to the config, it has no effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create ipython profile if not exists and override style

check if `ipython_config.py` presents under `~/.ipython/profile_default/` if not then you can run this command to create it

```sh
ipython profile create
```

open `ipython_config.py` file in any editor of your like and uncomment and update this option

```
from pygments.token import Token
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.highlighting_style_overrides = {
    Token.MatchingBrackets.Other  : '#FF00FF', # nested brackets color
    Token.MatchingBracket.Other   : '#FF00FF', # bracket color
    Token.MatchingBracket.Cursor  : '#4b3588', # on cursor over bracket color
    Token.MatchingBrackets.Cursor : '#4b3588', # on cursor over nested matching brackets color
}
```

For Build in token check [here](https://pygments.org/docs/tokens/), for Styling info check [here](https://pygments.org/docs/styles/)

For how i get to know [ipython](https://ipython.org) uses [pygments](https://pygments.org) for customization check [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/details.html#terminal-colors)

Comment: thank you. This changes the color of the bracket. Any way to change the color of the cursor as well, when the cursor is over the bracket?

Comment: @400theCat updated config for cursor color over brackets.

Comment: this solution no longer works for `ipython3` version `8.5.0`. When I add it to the config, it has no effect

Answer (score 1):

You can create ipython profile if not exists and change theme

check if `ipython_config.py` presents under `~/.ipython/profile_default/` if not then you can run this command to create it

```sh
ipython profile create
```

open `ipython_config.py` file in any editor of your like and uncomment and update these options as you like

```
c.InteractiveShell.color_info = True

c.InteractiveShell.colors = 'Linux'

c.TerminalInteractiveShell.highlighting_style = 'monokai'

c.TerminalInteractiveShell.highlight_matching_brackets = True
```

Comment: thank you. This has effect on the colors inside the parenthesis, but the matching parenthesis highlighting is still the same. ie the cursor background is white, as before

Answer (score -1):

In your Terminal, click Edit > Profile Preferences > Colors

See the Text and Background Color.
[image]

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with my terminal settings. I have same problem when I launch ipython from console (no terminal emulator)